# Как использовать второй аргумент this в forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Всем привет.

Сегодня читая документацию реакта столкнулся с таким кодом

```
{React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
   console.log(child);
})}
```

Сначало подумал что это какой нибудь фокус Реакта потом узнал что нет это чистый JS.

То есть `forEach` принимает вторым аргументом `this` но абсолютно нигде нету про это инфы посмотрел много где даже в  книге Дэвида Флэнагана JS подробное руководство . Нашел очень мало ресурсов про this и то они говорят что он есть но как использовать никто не сообщает.[Learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru) и то там только написано вот так:

> Второй, необязательный аргумент `forEach` позволяет указать контекст
>   this для callback. Мы обсудим его в деталях чуть позже, сейчас он нам
>   не важен.

Вот тут есть [небольшая инфа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).И конечно [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).Но нигде нету пример с **this**

Очень хотел увидеть пример forEach с использованием **this**.Приветствуется  развернутые ответы.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - `thisArg`

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19

Comment: Довольно часто при работе с массивами используется [передача контекста](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/search?page=1&q=%5B%2C+thisArg%5D).

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ужасно написано.

Comment: @Demon__ANT это же спецификация, она всегда такая

Comment: @РустамГимранов объяснений почти нету.Все примеры для каллбэка в forEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно надумано, но вот:

```js
function setStyle(entry) {
  // вот этот this привязывается через второй аргумент forEach
  this.style[entry[0]] = entry[1];
}

let props = Object.entries({
  color: 'red',
  fontSize: '30px'
});

props.forEach(setStyle, d1); // устанавливаем все св-ва из объекта элементу d1
props.forEach(setStyle, d2); // устанавливаем все св-ва из объекта элементу d2
```

```html
<div id="d1">1</div>
<div id="d2">2</div>
```

Comment: очень интересный код.спасибо